# Convert java.util.Date value to string using EL

Tags: jsf, jstl, el

How to compare `java.util.Date` value with `String` using JSTL and EL?

This is the model:

```
private Date myDate; // Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1001
```

This is the view:

```
<c:if test="#{bean.myDate eq 'Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1001'}">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.myDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEEE dd MMM yyyy @ HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
</c:if>
```

However the condition always evaluates false. How is how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your environment supports EL 2.2, just call its [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) method directly.

```html
<c:if test="#{bean.myDate.toString() eq 'Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1001'}">
```

If yours doesn't, convert it to `String` first by inlining it as body of `<c:set>`.

```html
<c:set var="myDate">#{bean.myDate}</c:set>
<c:if test="#{myDate eq 'Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1001'}">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a rather strange way of comparing dates. It's very sensitive to changes in locale and timezone (if the webpage visitor uses a non-English locale and your webapp supports non-English locales, then the test on `Wed Jan` would fail and if the webserver is moved to non-CET timezone, then the test on `CET` would fail). Don't you rather want to compare it on year `1001` directly or a fixed pattern such as `1001-01-01` or so? Further I also wonder why you don't do the test in the `rendered` attribute of the JSF `<h:outputText>` component.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "compare on year directly or so"?

Comment: Works for me with JSTL 1.2 on Mojarra 2.1.14. I recall some problems when MyFaces is used. What JSF impl/version are you using? And what JSTL version? Does your environment really not support EL 2.2? Some of your previously asked questions implies that you're using Java EE 6 and thus implicitly Servlet 3.0 and thus implicitly EL 2.2. What servletcontainer impl/version are you actually using? As to comparing on year, just check if year equals 1001 or a fixed pattern without locale/timezone sensitiveness such as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @BalusC  `public Boolean getShow(){
  if(this.myDate.toString()
   .equals("Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1001")){
   // do not show it
   return false;
  }else{
   return true;
  }
 }`  and in IHM I do this :  `<h:outputText value="#{bean.myDate }" rendered="#{bean.show}">
     </h:outputText>`

Answer (score 0):

in jsf 1.2

this code works for me :

```
                           <webuijsf:button
                            actionExpression="#{guiRettificaBilPuntuale_2.button4_action}"
                            id="button4" text="#{bundle.TastoModificaRiga}" 
                            rendered="#{ bilDetailsTable.value.settStatus eq 'N' or bilDetailsTable.value.starttime eq aLGUISessionBean_01.monthCurrentPublBilDate ? false : true}">
```

and starttime  and monthCurrentPublBilDate  are both dates (java.Date)  so you can transform string in Date and compare them